# SqlDataReader read whole query

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sqldatareader

I have a SQL script with a loop. In each iteration I change the where clause. So I get several selects displayed. But my .net program reads only the first select. The SQL script works in ssms.

This is my SQL script

```
while (@aktuellParam <= @countParam)
Begin
  SELECT name1,
         name2
  FROM dbo.tableName
  WHERE name like @var
  SET @aktuellParam = aktuellParam+1
END
```

This is my vb.net code

```
Using reader As SqlClient.SqlDataReader = _server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteReader(script)
    Dim lfdnr As Integer = 1

    Do While reader.Read()
        spaltenListe.Add(New ISpalten With
                                 {
                                     .Name1= reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name1")),
                                     .Name2= reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("name2"))
                                 })
        lfdnr = lfdnr + 1
    Loop
    reader.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: Read about using a Common Table Expression

Comment: That's because subsequent selects are actually in a different result set. Your reader needs to do a .NextResult after each read.

Comment: Why the rbar? What's wrong with a single select and BETWEEN operator?

Comment: @Ghost thank you that's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @mxix My select is more complicated than the code I posted. I give the SQL script a XML with different numbers of parameters, which are used in the where clause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because subsequent selects are actually in a different result set. Your reader needs to do a .NextResult after each read.